# Binary Search Tree Movie Database Project

Tags: c++, file-io, binary-search-tree

I am working on a project right now that is meant to act as a small movie database. The binary search tree is meant to read info from this file: http://www2.cs.uidaho.edu/~bruceb/cs121/Assignments/movies.txt The program needs to be able to do a few things: Print out all the movie titles and only the titles, have the user input an actor and have the program print all the movies said actor is in, have the user input a title and the program will display all the actors in the film, and have the program print out all films released before 1975. I'm very new to BSTs, so this has been especially difficult for me. **I am not asking for any code, just advice on how to begin.** Would it be better to have the user input something, then have the program search the file for that info, or would it be better to read the entire file into the tree first, and then search for the info in the tree? Any advice/tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Obvious starting point: SQL. Obvious starting point in C++: [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A binary search tree is a data structure used to store data; it has the capability of searching and inserting with a good comlexity(log(n)n). 
 We have two types of binary search tree: a non-balanced tree and a balanced binary search tree(a little bit more efficient).
A simple binary tree is easy to implement: you can find useful information about it on wikipedia.
You have multiple types of balanced BSTs: The 2-3 Binary Search Tree, the Red-Black Tree....
However, the implementation of balanced BSTs is fraught with peril.

Answer (score 0):

Design of the solutions would be based on search keys; movieNames, actors, release dates.

Read the input file and group Movies together in a tree with each node of tree looking like :

```
struct Movie{

string name;
int releaseYear;
vector<Actor*> actorsInMovie;
static map<int, list<Movie*> > movieReleaseByYearMap;
//or if just movie name is required then
// static map<int, list<string> > movieReleaseByYearMap;
}m1;
```

Note there is static map which is to be used to store movies against release date.

In addition to above create another tree which stores all actors, each node defined as:

```
struct Actor{

string name;
vector<Movie*> moviesDone;
 //if only movie name is required then
 // vector<string> moviesDone;
}actor1;
```

For Persistence these structures can be store in database or in memory like REDIS ( structures stored against keys (movie names with movie struct,actor names with movie keys , release date with movie keys ) )